# apache mod-rewrite removing www from url

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I want to remove www. from my site url.
I have added this to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works if I type www.domain.com/x but not if I type www.domain.com/x/y. The rewrite "eats" the x value.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a file (regular file or directory) with a name of *x*?

Comment: Have you tried including `RewriteBase /` ?

Comment: is this the only .htacess file you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
 RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

for your rewrite rule instead.